# Python : execute the queries parallely by reading from a single file

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Python3.6
I have bunch of queries (2000+) in a single file. I can connect to the DB and execute  one by one.

how can I run 5 threads and run 5 queries parallel in these threads, by reading from this file so that I can save time ? any sample code will be a great help...

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: please, if you post some question in stackoverflow.com, add the source code of your try, also if it's not working. Thanks

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I run 5 threads and run 5 queries parallel in these threads, by reading from this file so that I can save time ?

To be honest, I highly doubt that multithreading is a good solution for this because your file isn't that big - just read it sequentially `with open()...`. Running this task concurrently wouldn't result in greater speed/performance.
Also, before you try multithreading in python, have a look at [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) or/and at [What is a global interpreter lock (GIL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-a-global-interpreter-lock-gil#1294402).